# Remove function with high cost in performance

Tags: javascript, lodash

I consider myself a newbie. So I have one question for you.

I have this function

```
$scope.addLeagueToLines = function(league) {

  league.active = !league.active;

  if (league.active && !_.contains($scope.lineLeagues, league)) {

    $scope.lineLeagues.push(league);

  }else {

    _.remove($scope.lineLeagues, function(lineLeague) {

      return _.contains(lineLeague, league);

    });
  }
};
```

in the first conditional `if`, everything is OK, it works properly, and it is pushing `league` fine and smooth. The issue comes, when I try to remove the `league` in the `else` part. Sometimes the `league` comes with a lot of data, lets say 200 items, so when you push the league is not an issue. The issue is when you try to remove those 200 items in the `else`, the app turns slow in that part.

So, what should I do to remove items in a better way in this function ?

I am working with `lodash`, just in case.

Is there any other info you would like to know?

**UPDATE**

this is what `$scope.lineLeagues` returns in a console log

```
[
  {
    "id": "1517",
    "composedId": "15170G",
    "name": "NBA - Team Totals",
    "lineType": "G",
    "part": "0",
    "offeringsAvailable": 2,
    "sport": {
      "id": 8
    },
    "active": true
  },
  {
    "id": "5932",
    "composedId": "59320G",
    "name": "NBA",
    "lineType": "G",
    "part": "0",
    "offeringsAvailable": 20,
    "sport": {
      "id": 8
    },
    "active": false
  }
]
```

parameter `league`

```
{
  "id": "1496",
  "composedId": "14961I",
  "name": "MLB (1I)",
  "lineType": "I",
  "part": "1",
  "offeringsAvailable": 30,
  "sport": {
    "id": 6
  },
  "active": false
}
```

Comment: You might be able to speed up the `contains` part by using an object as a hastable. Do the `league`s have some id or so that makes them hashable?

Comment: So `$scope.lineLeagues` is an array of arrays of objects?

Comment: @Bergi actually every league comes with an `id`, but I don't get your point. Sorry

Comment: @Bergi see the update I did, please

Comment: Wait, your current code does not make sense. Are you sure that you need that `_.contains` in the `remove` predicate? Does it work as expected at all (even if slowly)? It might help if you could post some sample data for `lineLeagues` (ah, you just did) and `league`.

Comment: @Bergi I still don't know If I need it, that is why I am here, my friend :)

Comment: @Bergi and yes, it is working as expected, but very very slow.

Comment: I think you actually would need to do [`_.pull($scope.lineLeagues, league)`](https://lodash.com/docs#pull). What do you expect the `leaguesToRemove` result to be?

Comment: @Bergi before I had it without the `leaguesToRemove` declaration, just the remove below the `else`. I declared `var leaguesToRemove = [];`

Comment: @Bergi just did it with `_.pull` and it is faster now. Is that proper way then ?

Comment: Well if you don't need `leaguesToRemove` and don't expect to use it, then you should just omit it. But I'm still having a hard time to understand what you expect the function to do. It does get an object, and has an array of such objects, and then what? Please explain in words.

Comment: I can't really believe that it did work with `_.contains` if it does now work with `pull`. Are you sure it really did remove the `league` at all?

Comment: @Bergi in `$scope.lineLeagues.push(league);` I am pushing `league` which is an obj like this: `{id: "1381", composedId: "13810T", name: "MLB - Team Totals", lineType: "T", part: "0"…}`, and in the `else` part, what I to do, is remove `league` from ``$scope.lineLeagues.push(league);``

Comment: @Bergi I am not sure, when I add the `league` in the `if`, I call to the DB is made, when I removes it, that call doesn't exist, but it is because of the `localForage` I am using

Comment: @Bergi now, with the `_.pull` I added, when I remove the item, the call to the DB exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want is

```
_.remove($scope.lineLeagues, function(lineLeague) {
  return lineLeague == league;
});
```

Not sure why that `_.contains` got in there. It needlessly enumerates all properties of the `lineLeague` (treating the object as a collection) and tries to find the `league` as a value in there.

You might also simplify it to

```
_.pull($scope.lineLeagues, league)
```

Comment: it is so weird. If I do the first thing or the second, is still slow, but if I do: `_.remove(_.pull($scope.lineLeagues, league));` it works properly fast :/

Comment: Uh, `_.remove(_.pull($scope.lineLeagues, league));` *cannot* be faster than `_.pull($scope.lineLeagues, league)`. There must be something else you're doing. Btw, how large is `$scope.lineLeagues`? 1000 items? 10000?

Comment: it is around 3000, but you don't open the 3000 in one hit.

Comment: Hm, 3000 objects in an array should be quite manageable for underscore.

Comment: stay here for 2 minutes. I will paste what the objects returns

Answer (score -1):

What are the items of the `$scope.lineLeagues` Array? It looks like they should be `league` objects.

If that's the case then I'm not sure about the logic in your `else` branch.

Shouldn't it be:

```
leaguesToRemove = _.remove($scope.lineLeagues, function(lineLeague) {
  return _.isEqual(lineLeague, league);
});
```

#### EDIT

After seeing the update to the question, with the contents of `$scope.lineLeagues`, I confirm that the problem is `_.contains(lineLeague, league);`.
At that point `lineLeague` is a JS object, and you're checking if it contains another object.
What really happens is that lodash will iterate your `$scope.lineLeagues` Array and then, for each object, will compare each property with the second argument you are passing to `_.contains()`: the `league` object.

Comment: not sure why I got a downvote. The answer should be correct. Have you tried it?

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Sorry. Actually is still very slow. I don't know what is going on.